# Makefile entrypoint not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, entry-point

I have installed vscode, but this message always opens (bottom right in the picture). I have attached a screenshot for you. Anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a multi-root workspace?  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/issues/90

Answer (score 5):

With a code structure like this:

```
myProject
  |
  |_ component1
     |_ src: cpp files
     |_ Makefile
  |_ component2
     |_ src: cpp files
     |_ Makefile
```

I resolved this problem by creating **Makefile** under **./myProject** with this content:

```
MAKE := make
all:
    $(MAKE) -C ./component1
    $(MAKE) -C ./component2
```